# Cannot run cucumber JUnit tests on Gradle

Tags: gradle, junit5, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to run a Cucumber / Selenium project using IntelliJ Community edition and Gradle 5.5.1.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
ProjectRoot
|
src---main---java
|
src---test---java---packagename---stepdefinitions---Steps.java
        |
        -----resources---feature---application.feature
```

My TestRunner class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:cucumber-report.json"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/feature"})
public class TestRunner {
}
```

When I try to run the TestRunner what I get is the following:

```
Testing started at 18:48 ...
> Task :cleanTest
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [org.fifthgen.scanmaltatesting.TestRunner](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.fifthgen'
version '1'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

wrapper.gradleVersion = '5.5.1'

def cucumberVersion = '4.7.2'
def junitVersion = '5.5.2'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'

    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:${cucumberVersion}"

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    scanForTestClasses = false
}
```

When I run the `test` task using Gradle, I get

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
18:52:41: Task execution finished 'test'.
```

Without the Cucumber scenarios being run.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem using serenitybdd, the answers doesn't solved my problem. Anything in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ˋRunWithˋ is a JUnit 4 mechanism. In order to use that with JUnit 5 platform mechanism you must include dependency on junit-vintage engine which allows running JUnit 4 tests on JUnit 5.

Alternatively you could change to the Cucumber engine for JUnit 5. I’m not sure though if it has already been released.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me:

```
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
```

and

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    scanForTestClasses = false
}
```

The "magic" here was `scanForTestClasses = false`. But of course in order to work it needs the combination above.

Comment: I didn't need the "scanForTestClasses=false", but I did need that testRuntimeOnly portion.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs,

> Cucumber is based on JUnit 4. If you’re using JUnit 5, remember to include junit-vintage-engine dependency, as well. For more information, please refer to JUnit 5 documentation.

Adding following dependencies made it work on IntelliJ:

```
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.2")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
```

Check [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running) for more details